# I don't see option to login to my google managed account from Chromium

Tags: chromium

I don't see option to login to my google managed account from Chromium.
looks like clean and new Chromium without any of my bookmarks (i need them to work) etc.

is this issue connected to:
`google-to-cut-off-other-chromium-based-browsers-from-access-to-services-such-as-sync` ?
(i can't put actual link here i guess?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It appears Chromium cannot use Google/Chrome Sync (for bookmarks, etc.). Since Chromium is open-source, Google wants to control who uses their services, just like not all Android OS smartphones can use Google Play app store until they sign an agreement with Google. It has to do with Google protecting its ecosystem, users, etc.
https://blog.chromium.org/2021/01/limiting-private-api-availability-in.html